# the zen of adwords

Tags: seo, google, search, google-ads

I'm a hardcore developer gone freelance and I'm getting more and more requests for adwords from my clients. I've just started to read up on it, and of course I'm starting with wikipedia and have moved onto the main site now.

I wanted to post here if anyone has some tips or some good blog entires that describe how it works. Strategy posts would be awesome.

As always, thanks!

Comment: I think that what you're asking is actually for tips on AdSense publishing, not AdWords. The product called AdSense is used for the orientation as a publisher getting paid for ads on your site and the product AdWords is when you consider it as an advertiser paying for your own ads that get clicked.

Comment: Nope, I'm just that much of a newb. Adwords, nevertheless thanks for clearing that part up.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew Goodman is one of the best authors on the subject of AdWords. His book "Winning Results using Google AdWords" (now in the second edition) is a must read and there's a shorter free guide available on his site at http://www.pagezero.com/publications/google-adwords-guide.php

You could also check out the PPC Hero blog at http://www.ppchero.com/ as it contains a wealth of useful articles on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I'd Say +1 for PPChero.com already mentioned and add http://ppcblog.com/blog/

In terms of learning, Google has a study guide for passing the test to become an AdWord certified Professional

http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=examstudy.cs&rd=1

that's about as comprehensive as it gets as far as I have seen, at least when it comes down to fundamental concepts.